# What are the consequences of not migrating to the new released google places sdk

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an android app that uses Google places SDK which includes Google place picker and autocomplete places.

Migrating into the new Google places SDK has resulted into a lot of new errors. So I want to know what are the consequences of not migrating into the new SDK until further notice e.g next year 2020.

Comment: See related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57895054/how-to-set-predictible-search-on-google-maps and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57712397/google-places-picker-not-working-anymore-says-the-places-api-for-ios-is-not-en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to migrate to the new Places SDK. There is no way to get around that if you want to continue using Google's Autocomplete service.

The old Places SDK for Android (and IOS too) was deprecated in January 2019 and turned off in July 2019. In addition, the Place Picker was turned off for good and is not available anymore.

All you need to do is follow [Google's migration guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration).

If you're getting errors while doing so and are unable to migrate, please post those errors so that we are able to help.