# Google Places Picker not working anymore, says: The Places API for iOS is not enabled. See the developer’s guide

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-places-api, gmsplacepicker, google-place-picker

I am getting the error:

Error:  The operation couldn’t be completed. The Places API for iOS is not enabled. See the developer's guide (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start) for how to enable the Google Places API for iOS.

Google Account for map services is configured properly, billings etc. already done.

Code used to present:

```
    let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    autocompleteController.delegate = self
    present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Place Picker for Android and iOS was deprecated in January 2019 and turned off in July 2019. It can't be used anymore. Refer to Google's [deprecation notice](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/placepicker):

> **Notice:** The Place Picker (Android, iOS) is deprecated as of January 29, 2019. This feature will be turned off on July 29, 2019,
>   and will no longer be available after that date.

You may want to have a look at the public feature request for Place Picker in Google's Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128304760

Also note that there's a new Places SDK for iOS that you need to migrate to if you want to use any of the [available Places services](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/intro#api-overview) (e.g. Place Autocomplete). Follow the steps in Google's [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/client-migration).

Hope this helps.