# Google place picker closes immediately

Tags: android, google-maps

I've setup all the things that are needed, but still whenever I open the google place picker it closes immediately after get loaded. I also tried by restricting api with my project package and SHA-1 key.

I added this dependency

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
```

In Manifest it has meta-data tag like

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

And permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

In activity

```
    if (hasPermissions()) {
        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
        try {
            startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("112233", e.getStackTrace().toString());
        }
    }
```

> Log is printing.

```
2019-11-03 17:07:31.625 20912-20912/com.kashif.locationsample D/ViewRootImpl@57f08c4[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0

2019-11-03 17:07:31.721 20912-20912/com.kashif.locationsample D/ViewRootImpl@57f08c4[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1

2019-11-03 17:07:31.837 20912-20912/com.kashif.locationsample D/ViewRootImpl@57f08c4[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1

2019-11-03 17:07:31.837 20912-20912/com.kashif.locationsample D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@d20f601[MainActivity]

2019-11-03 17:07:31.837 20912-20912/com.kashif.locationsample D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310

2019-11-03 17:07:32.519 20912-20912/com.kashif.locationsample D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=87

2019-11-03 17:07:33.149 20912-20912/com.kashif.locationsample D/ViewRootImpl@57f08c4[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1

2019-11-03 17:07:33.150 20912-20912/com.kashif.locationsample D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@d20f601[MainActivity]

2019-11-03 17:07:33.150 20912-20912/com.kashif.locationsample D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310

2019-11-03 17:07:33.151 20912-20912/com.kashif.locationsample D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@d20f601[MainActivity]

2019-11-03 17:07:33.151 20912-20912/com.kashif.locationsample D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310

2019-11-03 17:07:33.151 20912-20912/com.kashif.locationsample V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=com.kashif.locationsample ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false

2019-11-03 17:07:33.151 20912-20912/com.kashif.locationsample D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0

2019-11-03 17:07:33.152 20912-20912/com.kashif.locationsample I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus

2019-11-03 17:07:33.154 20912-20912/com.kashif.locationsample D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=87

2019-11-03 17:07:33.155 20912-20912/com.kashif.locationsample D/ViewRootImpl@57f08c4[MainActivity]: setWindowStopped(false) old=false
```

Comment: Please show your error log

Comment: @AnisurRahmanTonu see Edited question, I've added logs

Comment: Is this complete log ?

Comment: Yes @AnisurRahmanTonu

Comment: See related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57712397/google-places-picker-not-working-anymore-says-the-places-api-for-ios-is-not-en

Answer (score 1):

Place picker is turned off by google on July 29, 2019.
[Place Picker is no longer available](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#place_picker_is_no_longer_available)

Comment: You may want to have a look at the public feature request for Place Picker in Google's Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128304810