# How to set predictible search on Google Maps?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want when a user is typing on the search field the seeker suggest the places, more expecific the bars.

All the tutorials are made with Places API and is deprecated. Is there any other solution, tutorial...?

Comment: What is wrong with places API?

Comment: it is deprecated and turned off

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration, try this its working and migrated with new places sdk

Answer (score 0):

The old Places SDK for Android is deprecated, but there is a new Places SDK you can [migrate to](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration) that offers the [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete) service you seem to be looking for.

Hope this helps you.