# Can not apply higher quota for google maps api

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, quota

I can not change the `places SDK for iOS & Android`, `limitation number for applying higher quota`.

when I click apply higher quota, it will link to [this page](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/usage-and-billing?hl=en_GB) and saw the warning notice on the page as below

> "Notice: If your iOS app is experiencing kGMSPlacesRateLimitExceeded
>   errors, you may be using a deprecated version of the Places SDK for
>   iOS. Version 2.7.0 of the Places SDK for iOS was deprecated as of
>   January 29, 2019, and was turned off on July 29, 2019. A new version
>   of the Places SDK for iOS is now available. We recommend updating to
>   the new version as soon as possible. For details, see the migration
>   guide."

**Is this the root cause? If we update the places SDK ,relase a new app version, then we can change the quota?**

thank you

Comment: First link seems to be broken

Comment: See related https://stackoverflow.com/a/57626263/11742502

Answer (score 0):

Yes, once you migrate to the new Places SDK for Android and IOS, you'll get unlimited daily quota by default; [Places API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/places-backend.googleapis.com) is the endpoint now for both SDKs, so make sure you have that API enabled on your project.

Please follow Google's [migration](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration) [guides](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/client-migration).

Hope this helps you.