# How do I increase quotas for Places SDK for Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am using Google place SDK for android. I want to request more quota limits.

> Users with an API key are allowed 1 000 requests per 24 hour period. Users who have also verified their identity through the APIs console are allowed 100 000 requests per 24 hour period. A credit card is required for verification, by enabling billing in the console

so I have followed the instructions :

1. Google Developers Console
2. Select Project, Expand API & Services , Click the Place SDK for Android, Go To Quota tab
3. In Requests--> Edit , I have clicked the 'Apply for higher quota' which redirect me to [Places SDK for Android Usage and Billing](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing?hl=en_US)

I read this document but I don't understand where should I place request for more quota.

Comment: Did you read: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Comment: See related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589374/what-are-the-consequences-of-not-migrating-to-the-new-released-google-places-sdk

Answer (score 1):

You're using the deprecated Places SDK for Android, which is why your quota is capped. The endpoint for the new SDK is [Places API](https://cloud.google.com/console/apis/library/places-backend.googleapis.com) which has unlimited daily quota set by default.

To migrate to the new Places SDK for Android, follow Google's [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration). Note that version 2.0.0 requires that you migrate to [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i migrate my project to AndroidX , and I'm using :     implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'
 .  but now Place SDK for android limo is zero. and also when i click Apply for higher quota  its open this page : https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing?hl=en_US

Comment: the daily quota you should be looking at is in https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/apis/places-backend.googleapis.com/quotas?project=

Comment: It should be set to unlimited by default. If it's capped at 1 then that means you don't have billing enabled on your project, please go to https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable?redirect=https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/start?dialogOnLoad%3Dbilling-enabled