# Android PlaceAutocompleteFragment auto closing

Tags: java, android, google-maps, search, google-places-api

I am trying to implement place PlaceAutocompleteFragment but issue is after click on search bar PlaceAutocompleteFragment is open for less than 1 sec. then  automatically closing. I tried with SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment also. Here my code

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);


<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value=".........."/>
```

**Note:** 
I enabled place search api in console and i also implemented place and location service in my project.

Comment: what error you get when fragment close automatically?

Comment: @Divyanshu Nothing is showing. Just closing without error or message.

Comment: @Divyanshu you are using deprecated code; you need to migrate to the new Places SDK for Android. Please check out these related threads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58639110/how-do-i-increase-quotas-for-places-sdk-for-android and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589374/what-are-the-consequences-of-not-migrating-to-the-new-released-google-places-sdk

Answer (score 0):

The Places SDK for Android introduces an all-new static library with updated functionality. The Google Play Services version of the Places SDK for Android (i.e. com.google.android.gms:play-services-places) is deprecated as of January 29, 2019, and will be turned off on July 29, 2019. A new version of the Places SDK for Android is now available.

[Migrating to the New Places SDK Client](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration)