# status statuscode=places_api_access_not_configured resolution=null problem

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I have a problem in my project. when i click search bar in top of screen then show an error the error is:

> status (statuscode=places_api_access_not_configured resolution=null)

my place api is enabled but I am still getting the error.

Here is my **Welcome.java**

```
public class Welcome extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener
{

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE=7000;
    private static final int PLAY_SERIVICES_RES_REQUEST=7001;

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location lastLocation;

    private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL=5000;
    private static int FATEST_INTERVAL=3000;
    private static int DISPLACEMENT=10;

    DatabaseReference drivers;
    GeoFire geoFire;
    Marker mCurrent;
    Switch location_switch;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    //car animation...
    private List<LatLng> polyLineList;
    private Marker carMarker;
    private float v;
    private double lat,lng;
    private Handler handler;
    private LatLng startPosition,endPosition,currentPosition;
    private int index,next;
    //private Button btnGo;
    private PlaceAutocompleteFragment places;
    private String destination;
    private PolylineOptions polylineOptions,blackPolylineOptions;
    private Polyline blackPolyline,greyPolyline;

    private IGoogleAPI mService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
         mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        //init view..
        location_switch= findViewById(R.id.location_switch);

        location_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isOnline) {
                if(isOnline)
                {
                    startLocationUpdate();
                    displayLocation();
                    Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(),"You are Online",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else
                {
                    stopLocationUpdate();
                    mCurrent.remove();
                    mMap.clear();
                    //handler.removeCallbacks(drawPathRunnable);
                    Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(),"You are Offline",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

        polyLineList=new ArrayList<>();



        //places Api....
        places=(PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
        places.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                if(location_switch.isChecked())
                {
                    destination=place.getAddress().toString();
                    destination=destination.replace(" ","+");

                    getDirection();
                }

                else {
                    Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "Please Change your status in Online", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, ""+status.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });



        //Geo fire

        drivers= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Drivers");
        geoFire=new GeoFire(drivers);
        setUpLocation();

        mService= Common.getGoogleAPI();
    }

    //we request run time permission ,we need override OnRequestPermission Result..
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if(grantResults.length>0&&grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    if(checkPlayServices())
                    {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                        createLocationRequest();
                        if(location_switch.isChecked())
                            displayLocation();
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    private void setUpLocation() {
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
           //Request Runtime permission...
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            },MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        else
        {
                if(checkPlayServices())
                {
                    buildGoogleApiClient();
                    createLocationRequest();
                    if(location_switch.isChecked())
                        displayLocation();
                }
        }
    }

    private void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest=new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
    }

    private void buildGoogleApiClient() {

        mGoogleApiClient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect(); //Connected Google api client.....
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode= GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if(resultCode!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
        {
            if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode))
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode,this,PLAY_SERIVICES_RES_REQUEST).show();
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "This device is not supported ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return false;

        }

        return true;
    }

    private void stopLocationUpdate() {

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            return;
        }

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);

    }

    private void displayLocation() {

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            return;
        }

        lastLocation=LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if(lastLocation!=null)
        {
            if(location_switch.isChecked())
            {
                final double latitude=lastLocation.getLatitude();
                final double longitude=lastLocation.getLongitude();

                //update firebase..
                geoFire.setLocation(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(), new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                        //add marker
                        if(mCurrent!=null)
                            mCurrent.remove();//marker remove already
                        mCurrent=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                                .position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude))
                                                .title("YOUR LOCATION"));
                        //Move camera from this position..
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,longitude),15.0f));

                        /*//draw animated rotated marker..
                        rotateMarker(mCurrent,-360,mMap);*/
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("ERROR","Cannot get your location");
        }

    }

    private void rotateMarker(final Marker mCurrent, final float i, GoogleMap mMap) {

        final Handler handler=new Handler();
        final long start= SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        final float startRotation=mCurrent.getRotation();
        final long duration=1500;

        final Interpolator interpolator=new LinearInterpolator();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long elapsed=SystemClock.uptimeMillis()-start;
                float t=interpolator.getInterpolation((float)elapsed/duration);
                float rot=t*i+(1-t)*startRotation;

                mCurrent.setRotation(-rot>180?rot/2:rot);

                if(t<1.0)
                {
                    handler.postDelayed(this,16);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void startLocationUpdate() {
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            return;
        }

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest,  this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        mMap.setTrafficEnabled(false);
        mMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);
        mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lastLocation=location;
        displayLocation();

    }







    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        displayLocation();
        startLocationUpdate();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {


    }
}
```

Hare is my **Android Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.ubarclone">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permisson.READ_GSERVICES" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Welcome"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

A screenshot of my issue: 
[image: search bar click]

When I click the search bar at the top this error message displays:
[image: error pic]

Comment: please go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54551166/how-to-resolve-places-api-access-not-configured

Comment: There is too much of code. Please reduce to [mre]

Comment: Did you configure API key restrictions for your application?

Comment: removed un-needed code to show to error better

Comment: @ManishNegi You are not initializing the API correctly. I would suggest you go read through googles examples. I edited your code to better highlight the error (see yellow box)

Comment: You need to migrate to the new Places SDK for Android. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58639110/how-do-i-increase-quotas-for-places-sdk-for-android