# My google places SDK doesn't seem to work after trying multiple options. What could the issue be?

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm using the google places SDk which I'm aware has deprecated. I'm using the AutoComplete functionality but constantly get errors that state there is a network error and the resolution is null. Is this because of the deprecation? Does it make a difference if my API Key is in my Manifest or can I store it anywhere I want (Ignore security purposes)?

Comment: I don't think it's deprecated. Paste the relevant code and the errors here.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Comment: D'oh, missed the android tag completely. Why not upgrade?

Comment: Upgrading takes a while because its a big project file. Also with the upgrade I'd have to find a way to implement Place Picker again because they've removed it. If I can get it to work without the upgrade then it's easier

Comment: It'd help to see the errors and your implementation, it could be that it's due to the deprecation or something more benign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the deprecated Places SDK anymore. You'll need to [migrate](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration) to the new Places SDK for Android if you want to continue using the Places service; there's no way you can get the deprecated SDK to work by this time.

Check out [What are the consequences of not migrating to the new released google places sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589374/what-are-the-consequences-of-not-migrating-to-the-new-released-google-places-sdk)

Note that you'll also need to migrate to [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) if you haven't done so yet either.

Hope this helps!